# io.netty.channel.unix.Errors$NativeIoException: readAddress(..) failed: Connection reset by peer

Tags: java, spring

I am using spring gateway to forward the api request, now I am facing a strange problem is that when I update the backend service, the api will resume for a very long time. But the back end service restart quickly, I am writen the backend service using rust, the restart will take less than 5 seconds, but the api resume will take more than 10 minites. I am confusing about this problem, my spring gateway forward config like this:

```
# dolphin music
spring.cloud.gateway.discovery.locator.enabled=true
spring.cloud.gateway.discovery.locator.lower-case-service-id=true
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].id=dolphin-music-service
# forward by ip:port way
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].uri=http://10.107.64.246:11014
# forward by service name way
# spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].uri=lb://
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].predicates[0]=Path=/music/**
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].filters[0].name=LogFilter2
```

before the api resume, when I invoke the api, the spring gateway will show error log like this:

```
  2021-10-09 17:29:19.077 WARN 1 --- [or-http-epoll-1] r.n.h.c.HttpClientConnect : [id: 0x3826e7e1, L:/10.97.196.228:39504 - R:10.107.64.246/10.107.64.246:11014] The connection observed an error

io.netty.channel.unix.Errors$NativeIoException: readAddress(..) failed: Connection reset by peer
```

I am using curl command in the spring gateway pod to invoke the backend service like this:

```
   # curl http://10.107.64.246:11014/music/playlist/v1/playlist -H "accessToken:1" -H "appId:4" -H "userId:16"|jq "."
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   899  100   899    0     0  30032      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 31000
{
  "result": [
    {
      "id": 2,
      "creator": {
        "id": 0,
        "name": "test",
        "avatarUrl": "https://p1.music.126.net/Ue_B2LOqrDupzKLRcxOlxQ==/109951165445776620.jpg",
        "nickname": "Xiaoqiang Jiang"
      },
      "name": "favirate",
      "coverUrl": "https://p1.music.126.net/Ue_B2LOqrDupzKLRcxOlxQ==/109951165445776620.jpg",
      "description": null,
      "subscribed": true,
      "subscribedCount": 0,
      "commentCount": 0,
      "shareCount": 0,
      "playCount": 0,
      "source": 3,
      "trackUpdateTime": 1626501600000,
      "trackCount": 0
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "creator": {
        "id": 0,
        "name": "test",
        "avatarUrl": "https://p1.music.126.net/Ue_B2LOqrDupzKLRcxOlxQ==/109951165445776620.jpg",
        "nickname": "Xiaoqiang Jiang"
      },
      "name": "discovery",
      "coverUrl": "https://p1.music.126.net/Ue_B2LOqrDupzKLRcxOlxQ==/109951165445776620.jpg",
      "description": null,
      "subscribed": true,
      "subscribedCount": 0,
      "commentCount": 0,
      "shareCount": 0,
      "playCount": 0,
      "source": 3,
      "trackUpdateTime": 1626501600000,
      "trackCount": 143
    }
  ],
  "statusCode": "200",
  "resultCode": "200"
}
```

shows that the backend service was UP right now, why the spring gateway tell that connection reset error althrough the backend service was UP? waht should I do to fix this problem?